# Jest: How to properly test a Javascript service using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, testing, jestjs

I'm a total beginner with Jest.

I've got a `UserService` using Dependency Injection.

```
public async getAll() {
  const userRecords = await this.userModel.find().select('name').catch((e) => {
    throw new HttpException(500, 'Error while fetching users.', e)
  });
  return <[IUser]>userRecords;
}
```

I would like to test this feature. Here are the tests I could run:

1. Calling the route, and checking if the resulting JSON is OK
2. Ggetting DB content, and checking if it is as expected
3. Just test the `getAll` function

I think 1 and 2 are obvious, and cover different kind of things. 1 covers the request part, 2 covers the DB part. But what about number 3? How to "just test" the `getAll` function?

I've tried this:

```
const userModel = {
  find: (user) => {
    return [
      { id: 'user1' },
      { id: 'user2' }
    ]
  },
};
const userService = new UserService(userModel);
const userRecords = await userService.getAll();

expect(argumentRecord).toBeDefined();
```

But obviously it's failing because `select is undefined`.

Should I also mock `select()`? Should I organize my code differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If were to write this test I would mock the functions using [`jest.fn(implementation)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestfnimplementation) so that expectations can be enforced on the function calls.

```
const userQuery = {
    select: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([]))
};

const userModel = {
    find: jest.fn(() => userQuery)
};

const userService = new UserService(userModel);
const userRecords = await userService.getAll();

expect(userRecords).toEqual([]);
expect(userModel.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(userQuery.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith('name');
```

Performing expectations on the function calls may sound like overkill, but it explicitly verifies that the mock is actually being used by `getAll`.

I would also structure the tests in such a way that I can test the various code paths without re-implementing the entire mock.

```
describe('getAll()', () => {

    let userQuery, userModel, userService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        userQuery = {
            select: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([]))
        };

        userModel = {
            find: jest.fn(() => userQuery)
        };

        userService = new UserService(userModel);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        expect(userModel.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(userQuery.select).toHaveBeenCalledWith('name');
    });

    it('should get the user names', async () => {
        const users = [{
            name: 'john'
        }, {
            name: 'jane'
        }];
        userQuery.select.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(users));

        await expect(userService.getAll()).resolves.toBe(users);
    });

    it('should handle errors', async () => {
        const error = new Error('Fake model error');
        userQuery.select.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(error));

        await expect(userService.getAll()).rejects.toMatch({
            status: 500,
            message: 'Error while fetching users.',
            cause: error
        });
    });
});
```

This code is untested, so it may not work correctly, but hopefully it outlines the idea sufficiently.

---

While this is not directly related to your question I would avoid mixing `async/await` with traditional promise handling.

```
public async getAll() {
    try {
        return <[IUser]> await this.userModel.find().select('name');
    } catch (e) {
        throw new HttpException(500, 'Error while fetching users.', e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should mock `select`. And not only that, but everything that is used inside the function and test if they are executed properly. I would do this:

```
class SomeClass {
    public async getAll() {
      const userRecords = await this.userModel.find().select('name').catch(this.errorHandler);

      return <[IUser]>userRecords;
    }

    public errorHandler(e) {
        throw new HttpException(500, 'Error while fetching users.', e);
    }
}

// this is just an example, it should be the same type as your expected returned output
const whatever = Math.random();

const fakeCatch = jest.fn(() => whatever);

const fakeSelect = jest.fn(() => {
    return {
        catch: fakeCatch
    }
});
const fakeFind = jest.fn(() => {
    return {
        select: fakeSelect
    };
});
const fakeUserModel = {
    find: fakeFind,
}

const userService = new UserService(fakeUserModel);
const userRecords = await userService.getAll();

// should return the correct result
expect(userRecords).toEqual(whatever);

// should execute find
expect(fakeFind).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

// should execute select with 'name' parameter
expect(fakeSelect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(fakeSelect).toHaveBeenCalledWith('name');

// should execute catch with this.errorHandler
expect(fakeCatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userService.errorHandler);
```